# Can't resize my array to a smaller size

Tags: arrays, ruby

I defined this `StackOfStringsArray` class that contains one array instance `@stringArray` and an array index variable, and as below I defined a `resize` method in it to make @stringArray resizable. I knew Ruby's array is natively sizeable, but I want to implement mine.

In addition, when I did the experiment in irb I could do it successfully (new a sized array and assign it to the `StackOfStringsArray` object's @stringArray, and I could see the @stringArray did have same size as the new array), but by using this `resize` method I can just make it becomes bigger size array but not smaller one, even though I'm sure it does go into this `resize` method.

Could some Ruby ninja help out? Thanks so much.

```
class StackOfStringsArray

  attr_accessor :stringArray, :index

  def initialize(size)
    @stringArray = Array.new(size)
    @index = 0
  end

  def resize(size)
    copy = Array.new(size)
    @stringArray.each_with_index do |element, index|
      copy[index] = element
    end 
    @stringArray = copy
  end 

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... I can just make it becomes bigger size array but not smaller one...
>
> ... I knew Ruby's array is natively sizeable ...

That is the root of your problem. You iterate the old, bigger array and the new copy resizes to accomodate all of its elements. To fix this, *take* no more than `size` elements from the old array.

<sup>Since this is a challenge you imposed upon yourself, I'm not giving you the actual code. This hint should be enough, I hope.</sup>

Comment: Thanks so much for this quick and thoughtful answer. I just solved it.